# MISRA-C Violations for function like macros in Trusted Firmware-A(TFA) code

Tags: c, arm, misra

It is observed that functions like macros like NOTICE, WARN and assert are present in the Trusted Firmware-A code. MISRA-C standard treats these as violations.
shall we take these as deviation? please suggest.

Here attached the MISRA violation,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQi9K.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2SvI.png)

TFA Guidelines recommends using logging macros. So can we make deviations or need to change the MACRO into function.

Comment: Remember that MISRA C provides guidelines, that are not meant to be blindly followed. Likewise, MISRA Compliance can be tailored.

Answer (score 3):

MISRA C:2012 checker violations against Directives is a bit fishy, since Directives are by their nature hard to analyze for a tool. Dir 4.9 is about not using function-like macros if a function can be used instead. The Directive is Advisory and in practice very hard to follow.

If the macro is present in a library you are using, then you don't really have the option to rewrite it as a function - these look like `printf` wrappers (which might be another problem because stdio.h is banned from production code).

If you think like function-like macros like these will be common, then maybe address Dir 4.9 in your MISRA C documentation and then block the rule in your tool. Otherwise if this is just a single case where you can't replace the macro with a function, maybe treat it as a code-specific deviation (even though the Directive is Advisory) according to your deviation procedure.